# defines from Windows.h in C#?

Tags: c#, winapi

Is there any easy way to get the defines (at least the WM_ stuff) from windows.h in C#?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, you can copy them out of the code listing here at the Pinvoke website:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/WindowsMessages.html

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to use the PInvoke Interop Assistant.  It contains a data base of almost every constant defined via windows.h and provides the ability to translate C header code on the fly.

http://www.codeplex.com/clrinterop

Comment: I find your answer better than mine :-)

Comment: @Yossarian I +1'd your answer as well.  Both are good tools. I'm just biased because i worked in the PInvoke Interop Assistant. :)

Answer (score 1):

Point your visual studio search to find in file i.e. where Platforms SDK is installed:

Eg: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.1\Include

Then search for constant.

You can use this article as reference :
How To Find Undocumented Constants Used by Windows API Functions :
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187674